# What are those structures in Sudan?

Tags: identify-this, africa, sudan

While flying back from La Réunion to Paris, we flew over those well defined structures:

[image]

I think it corresponds to this location on the map:

https://goo.gl/maps/Wz1paAFsGGQjULYa7

At 13.9916°N, 35.9597°E.

Do you know what those are? Is this a refugee camp? There are refugee camps a few km away (Shagarab Refugees camp) but they look much less structured.

Reverse image search didn't bring anything interesting.

Comment: A very similar structure exists further along the river: https://goo.gl/maps/GfQuMXqGJuLRQ2V89

Comment: @victor-le-pochat you beat me to it. The mosque in that compound has some photographs https://maps.app.goo.gl/sxVMeto1DRRp5FS78

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This area is called "Fushqa" (Arabic: فشقة), it's a border area between Sudan and Ethiopia which was disputed, now it belongs to Sudan.

The structured area you see is a "modern" village, built by the government of Sudan for the local farmers to encourage them to stay since the land is fertile and being a disputed land with a few attacks from Ethiopian militias people needed a good reason to feel safe and stay, building these villages provide some sort of security better than having them scattered around a huge area with no facilities.

Sources: [1](https://www.marefa.org/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B4%D9%82%D8%A9), [2](https://www.alhurra.com/sudan/2020/04/10/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A5%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B4%D9%82%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%87%D9%8A-%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%9F)

Comment: Excellent, thanks. It could fit well. Just curious : how did you find it?

Comment: @EricDuminil it was easy since I read Arabic, just going around the place in google maps till i got a lead.

Comment: For me Google maps shows `Al Fushqa` in English, but further googling doesn't show anything interesting. @NeanDerThal: Can you link to the source, even if it's in Arabic?

Comment: @jonathan sure, [1](https://www.marefa.org/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B4%D9%82%D8%A9), [2](https://www.alhurra.com/sudan/2020/04/10/%D8%AA%D8%B5%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AA%D9%88%D8%AA%D8%B1-%D8%A8%D9%8A%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%88%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A5%D8%AB%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%B4%D9%82%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%A7-%D9%87%D9%8A-%D8%A3%D8%B3%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%9F)